# is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I really can't understand what the problem is here and why I'm getting this error

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var V_Model = new V_ViewModel() { TagName=V_Model.TagName};

        return View(V_Model);
    }

public class V_ViewModel
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

The Error:

> is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Isn't it the way to use View Model in MVC?

Comment: I'm sure the actual error message includes a *name* of some description, e.g. `V_ViewModel is a type but is used like a variable`. Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: var V_Model = new V_ViewModel() { TagName=V_Model.TagName};
=> This line doesnt make sense.

Comment: var NovoViewModel = new NovoViewModel() { tag = NovoViewModel.tag.TagName }; This is also the same Error.

Comment: Cannot use local variable 'testModel' before it is declared

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have another class called `V_Model`.  The compiler is then telling you that the type `V_Model` is being used as a variable:

Also, if you do not have a class called `V_Model` you are attempting to create a new instance of `V_ViewModel` called `V_Model` and assign it's `TagName` to a variable that has not been created.

Rename `V_Model` to something else and remove `TagName = V_Model.TagName`

```
var testModel = new V_ViewModel() { TagName = "TestTag" };
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr. @Darren Davies I have tried new class(viewModel) & using the class name as var , didn't changed a thing

Comment: var testModel = new V_ViewModel() { TagName = "TestTag" }; is working but testModel.TagName . is not

Comment: Cannot use local variable 'testModel' before it is declared